# How to apply a custom pipe to ngFor iteration elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular6

I have a custom pipe to highlight text. I want to apply this pipe to ngfor iteration elements. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```js
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'highlight' })
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string, search): string {
    if (search && text) {
      let pattern = search.toString().replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
      pattern = pattern.split(' ').filter((t) => {
        return t.length > 0;
      }).join('|');
      const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');

      return text.toString().replace(regex, (match) => `<span class="search-highlight">${match}</span>`);
    } else {
      return text;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
:host ::ng-deep .search-highlight{
  background-color: #F2E366;
}
```

```html
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of (itemsList | highlight)">
          <td><i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-paperclip':item.ext === 'pdf'}"></i></td>
          <td>{{item.name}}<span [innerHTML]="text | highlight: searchTerm"></span></td>
          <td>{{item.path}}</td>
          <td>{{item.dateModification | date:'short':'':'fr'}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: are you getting the searchTerm data in your pipe component?

Comment: @ChellappanV, I don't think so.

Comment: here is the link in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrd9ob

Comment: stackblitz is broken can you change your application code like this <td>{{item.name}}<span [innerHTML]="text | highlight: searchTerm.value">

Comment: Do I need to import the pipe.ts in the component.ts?

Comment: no need to import. you are trying to pass the template variable to pipe since you are passing template variable you need to mention what you want to pass value only so change your searchTerm to   searchTerm.value

Comment: @ChellappanV here is my code for now:
`<td>{{item.name}}<span [innerHTML]="item.name | highlight: searchTerm.value"></span></td>`, and it works.
the typo was in `"text | highlight: searchTerm"`.

Comment: now it is working right?

Comment: Yes @ChellappanV, it is working.

Answer (score 1):

After @ChellappanV comments, specially this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484728/how-to-apply-a-custom-pipe-to-ngfor-iteration-elements#comment87985133_50484728), I changed my code in the search.component.html as following:

`<td>{{item.name}}<span [innerHTML]="item.name | highlight: searchTerm.value"></span></td>`

instead of:

`<td>{{item.name}}<span [innerHTML]="text | highlight: searchTerm"></span></td>`